# How to decode using libx264 package?

Tags: x264, libx264, libx265

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04, package libx264-148

I am looking at decoding some x264-encoded data using libx264 library. I found a sample at https://code.videolan.org/solaris/x264/raw/7d35ba6bf080610d8f144f4270e961c69ba14f1c/x264.c. It is using APIs such as `x264_decoder_open` and `x264_decoder_decode.` However, when I examine `/usr/include/x264.h,` I see APIs only for encoding such as `x264_encoder_open` and `x264_encoder_encode.` There are no APIs for decoding. I am wondering if I am missing something. Are we supposed to use the same APIs for encoding as well as decoding? Also, pointer to any code sample will be highly appreciated. Regards.

PS: It is a similar issue with x265.h as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything. x264 doesn't decode, its an encoder only

Comment: Thank you szatmary. Is there any alternative library to decode? What is ffmpeg using?

Comment: Ffmpeg uses ffmpeg. They wrote their own.